# Merge two List into One With Splitting Overlaps According to Priority C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, merge, split

I have these two Lists scheduled with Priority 1 and registered With Priority 0:

[image]

Result should be:

[image]

I want to merge two Lists into one with checking priority. Priority rows will be entered without splitting. But unprioritized row can be split.

Comment: Post some code from what you've tried so far.

Comment: You say "scheduled with Priority 1 and registered With Priority 0" and then "unprioritized row can be split" - what makes a row "unprioritized"? All rows have a priority, either 0 or 1 in your data.

Comment: @NetMage I would say a prioritized row is one which has a priority value of 1. But to the poster: there are two parts of your question, the first is to come up with an algorithm which does what you want to do, and the second is to write that in C#. Assuming this is an assignment, you should come up with the algorithm yourself, and try to implement it yourself, and only ask for help here if you get stuck on that part.

Comment: Hi NetMage, Scheduled one always has the first priority. Your Code is working in many scenarios. But I found one scenario in which it is not working. [CheckThisLink](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/1Kxx)

Comment: Hi @NetMage, I have another problem. Will you please help me in that also - [Problem Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59405450/merge-two-list-in-a-way-to-cover-full-hours)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Scheduled` contains all priority 1 periods, and that `Registered` contains all priority 0 periods (and these are considered *unprioritized*), and assuming your periods are in a class named `ClassPeriod` and assuming `Priority` is a `Nullable` to represent the blank column in your result diagram (your question should have answered all of these clearly), then you can define a helper method in `ClassPeriod`:

```
public class ClassPeriod {
    public double From;
    public double To;
    public int? Priority;

    public bool ContainsFrom(ClassPeriod aCP) => From <= aCP.From && aCP.From < To;
    public bool ContainsTo(ClassPeriod aCP) => From < aCP.To && aCP.To <= To;
}
```

Now you can compute your answer as:

```
var ans = Scheduled
            .Select(s => new ClassPeriod { From = s.From, To = s.To })
            .Concat(
                Registered.SelectMany(r => {
                    var ans = new List<ClassPeriod>();
                    while (r.From < r.To) {
                        var pcp = new ClassPeriod {
                            From = Scheduled.Where(s => s.ContainsFrom(r)).Select(s => s.To).DefaultIfEmpty(r.From).Max(),
                            To = Scheduled.Where(s => s.ContainsTo(r)).Select(s => s.From).DefaultIfEmpty(r.To).Min()
                        };

                        var nexts = Scheduled.Where(s => pcp.ContainsFrom(s));
                        if (nexts.Any()) {
                            var nextTo = nexts.Min(s => s.From);
                            ans.Add(new ClassPeriod { From = pcp.From, To = nextTo });
                            r.From = nextTo;
                        }
                        else {
                            if (pcp.From < pcp.To)
                                ans.Add(pcp);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    return ans;
                })
            )
            .OrderBy(cp => cp.From).ThenBy(cp => cp.To);
```

Comment: Hi NetMage, Your code is very good. But it is failing in one scenario. Please help me in this. Check this [Working Code Link](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/1Kxx). I have created the scenario and written what result should come.

Comment: @kapilkumar In your example, what happened to the registered 9 To 9.10 and 9.10 To 9.15? Were they discarded?

Comment: @kapilkumar I modified my answer to handle splitting Registered periods when they completely overlap Scheduled periods. It is more complicated now.

Comment: ThankYou for your code. It is working perfectly fine.  You are a savior man. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @NetMage, I got stuck in one more problem. Will you please help me in that also - [Problem Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59405450/merge-two-list-in-a-way-to-cover-full-hours)