# Merge Two List in a way to cover full hours

Tags: c#, algorithm, merge, split, logic

I have two lists Schedule(Having Total Hours) And Registered (Having Time Intervals). I want to create a list that is having registered time covered with Schedule list total hours finished.

[image: Scenario Image]

See the Upper image. The resultant list is covering Registered Times and ENd if it doesn't find any registration for left hours. It will just create further times according to hours left with their types.

Comment: Can you please share what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Hi @stud3nt, I have tried something but that implementation is very much complicated and also not working. You can have a look - [Tried Code](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/1LNl)

Comment: It really helps if you give an example of what you expect your output to look like, instead of just trying to describe it.

Comment: Hi @Knoop, In the above image I have explained the Inputs and it respective output

Comment: @kapilkumar I know, but there's no example. There are a lot of people for whom English is not their first language, so while the description might seem clear to you it doesn't have to be clear for others. That's why an example of `input A -> output B` helps a lot to communicate your wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this sample:

```
    class Task
    {
        public int duration;
        public string type;
        public int remaining;
        public void Reset()
        {
            remaining = duration;
        }
    }
    class Span
    {
        public int from;
        public int to;
        public int remaining;
        public int duration => to - from;
        public void Reset()
        {
            remaining = duration;
        }
    }

    struct Assignment
    {
        public Span span;
        public string type;
    }
    static IEnumerable<Assignment> AssignTasks(List<Task> tasks, List<Span> spans)
    {
        // add an infinite span to the end of list
        spans.Add(new Span()
        {
            from = spans.Last().to,
            to = int.MaxValue
        });
        // set remainings of tasks and spans by their total duration
        foreach (Task task in tasks) { task.Reset(); }
        foreach (Span span in spans) { span.Reset(); }
        // set current task and span
        int iTask = 0;
        int iSpan = 0;
        while (iTask < tasks.Count)
        {
            //find which is smaller: remaining part of current task, or 
            // remaining part of current span
            int assigning =
            tasks[iTask].remaining <= spans[iSpan].remaining ?
                tasks[iTask].remaining : spans[iSpan].remaining;
            // add a new assignment to results
            yield return new Assignment()
            {
                span = new Span()
                {
                    from = spans[iSpan].to - spans[iSpan].remaining,
                    to = spans[iSpan].to - spans[iSpan].remaining + assigning,
                },
                type = tasks[iTask].type
            };
            // update remaining parts of current task and span
            tasks[iTask].remaining -= assigning;
            spans[iSpan].remaining -= assigning;
            // update counters if nothing is left 
            if (tasks[iTask].remaining == 0)
                iTask++;
            if (spans[iSpan].remaining == 0)
                iSpan++;
        }

    }
```

In this piece of code, `Task` is equivalent to what you call "Scheduled", and `Span` is equivalent to "Registered". I removed `From` and `To` from `Task` because they seem irrelevant to the problem. I also added a `Remaining` field to both `Task` and `Span` classes, I use these to keep the unassigned part of tasks or spans since a portion of a task can be assigned to a portion of a span.

The key point, to make everything much easier, is adding an infinite span to the end of list of spans. Now there are more registered spans (resources) than our demands and we just need to simply assign them.

You can test it like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>()
        {
            new Task() {duration = 4, type = "A"},
            new Task() {duration = 2, type = "B"},
            new Task() {duration = 6, type = "C"},
            new Task() {duration = 8, type = "D"}
        };
        List<Span> spans = new List<Span>()
        {
            new Span() {from = 9, to = 10},
            new Span() {from = 11, to = 13},
            new Span() {from = 15, to = 20}
        };
        IEnumerable<Assignment> assignments = AssignTasks(tasks, spans);

        Console.WriteLine("Tasks: duration, type");
        foreach (Task task in tasks)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{task.duration}, {task.type}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nSpans: from, to");
        foreach (Span span in spans)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{span.from}, {span.to}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nResults: from, to, type");
        foreach (Assignment assignment in assignments)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{assignment.span.from}, {assignment.span.to}, {assignment.type}");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The outcome is:

> Tasks: duration, type
>   4, A
>   2, B
>   6, C
>   8, D
>
> Spans: from, to
>   9, 10
>   11, 13
>   15, 20
>
> Results: from, to, type
>   9, 10, A
>   11, 13, A
>   15, 16, A
>   16, 18, B
>   18, 20, C
>   20, 24, C
>   24, 32, D

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

The following enum and classes represent the input format you requested.

```
public enum SType
{
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D
}
public class Schedule : Register
{
    public SType Type { get; set; }
    public Schedule(int from, int to, SType type) : base(from, to)
    {
        Type = type;
    }
}

public class Register
{
    public int From { get; set; }
    public int To { get; set; }
    public int TotalHours => To - From;
    public Register(int from, int to)
    {
        From = from;
        To = to;
    }
}
```

Then, following your sample input:

```
var scheduled = new List<Schedule>()
{
    new Schedule(0, 4, SType.A),
    new Schedule(4, 6, SType.B),
    new Schedule(6, 12, SType.C),
    new Schedule(12, 20, SType.D)
};

var registered = new List<Register>()
{
    new Register(9, 10),
    new Register(11, 13),
    new Register(15, 20)
};
```

This will retrieve the requested output:

```
var result = new List<Schedule>();
int elapsedHours = 0;

foreach (var s in scheduled)
{
    int hours = s.TotalHours;

    foreach (var r in registered)
    {
        if (elapsedHours <= r.To)
        {
            int from = Math.Max(elapsedHours, r.From);

            if (r.TotalHours <= hours)
            {
                elapsedHours = r.To;
                result.Add(new Schedule(from, elapsedHours, s.Type));
                hours -= (elapsedHours - from);
            }
            else
            {     
                elapsedHours = from + hours;
                result.Add(new Schedule(from, elapsedHours, s.Type));                      
                hours = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    if (hours > 0)
    {
        result.Add(new Schedule(elapsedHours, elapsedHours + hours, s.Type));
        elapsedHours += hours;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following classes to represent your source data:

```
public class Schedule {
    public int From;
    public int To;
    public int TotalHours => To - From;
    public string Type;

    public Schedule(int from, int to, string type) {
        From = from;
        To = to;
        Type = type;
    }
}

public class Register {
    public int From;
    public int To;

    public Register(int from, int to) {
        From = from;
        To = to;
    }
}
```

Here is a `for` loop implementation that spreads each Schedule member across the Registered time intervals and then outputs the rest:

```
var ans = new List<Schedule>();

int currentRegistered = 0;
var rp = registered[currentRegistered];
var currentFrom = rp.From;

for (int curScheduled = 0; curScheduled < scheduled.Count; ++curScheduled) {
    var s = scheduled[curScheduled];
    for (var hours = s.TotalHours; hours > 0;) {
        if (currentFrom >= rp.To)
            rp = (++currentRegistered < registered.Count)
                    ? registered[currentRegistered]
                    : new Register(currentFrom, int.MaxValue);
        if (rp.From > currentFrom)
            currentFrom = rp.From;

        var newTo = (rp.To - currentFrom > hours) ? currentFrom + hours : rp.To;
        ans.Add(new Schedule(currentFrom, newTo, s.Type));
        hours -= newTo - currentFrom;
        currentFrom = newTo;
    }
}
```